# Check if the node value exist

Tags: xpath

I want to check in a xml if there is a node with the value "Hotel Hafen Hamburg".

But I get the error.

> SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Invalid predicate on line 25

You can view the xml here.

http://de.sourcepod.com/dkdtrb22-19748

Until now I have written the following code.

```
$apiUmgebungUrl = "xml.xml";
$xml_umgebung = simplexml_load_file($apiUmgebungUrl);
echo $nameexist = $xml_umgebung->xpath('boolean(//result/name[@Hotel Hafen Hamburg');
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems that your parantheses and brackets do not close properly at the end of your XPath expression - it should end on `])`.

Also, what is *Hotel Hafen Hamburg*? If it is an attribute called `value`, your value check should look like this:

```
[@value="Hotel Hafen Hamburg"]
```

You cannot just write `@` and then a value, without specifying *where* that value is supposed to be.

EDIT: Looking at the Xml document, it seems that *Hotel Hafen Hamburg* is supposed to be the text content of the `<name>` element. Therefore, try looking for a text node with that value rather than an attribute:

```
boolean(//result/name[text() = "Hotel Hafen Hamburg"])
```

Comment: thank you. but there is already a mistake, because i get this error message Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): Invalid expression on line 25

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath(): xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed  on line 25

Comment: @susi87: Sorry, there was an obsolete slash in front of the opening bracket - can you try again? It seems to work [on this testbed](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).